# Arrange many plots using gridExtra

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I have spent many hours trying to fit 11 graphs in one plot and arrange them using `gridExtra` but I have failed miserably, so I turn to you hoping you can help.

I have 11 classifications of diamonds (call it `size1`) and other 11 classifications (`size2`) and I want to plot how the median price for each increasing `size1` and increasing `clarity` (from 1 to 6) varies by increasing `size2` of the diamonds, and plot all the 11 plots in the same graph. 
I tried using `gridExtra` as suggested in other posts but the legend is far away to the right and all the graphs are squished to the left, can you please help me figure out how the "widths" for the legend in `gridExtra` has to be specified? I cannot find any good explanations. Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it...

I have been trying to find a good example to recreate my data frame but failed in this as well. I hope this data frame helps understand what I am trying to do, I could not get it to work and be the same as mine and some plots don't have enough data, but the important part is the disposition of the graphs using `gridExtra` (although if you have other comments on other parts please let me know):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

df <- data.frame(price=matrix(sample(1:1000, 100, replace = TRUE), ncol = 1))

df$size1 = 1:nrow(df)
df$size1 = cut(df$size1, breaks=11)
df=df[sample(nrow(df)),]
df$size2 = 1:nrow(df)
df$size2 = cut(df$size2, breaks=11)
df=df[sample(nrow(df)),]
df$clarity = 1:nrow(df)
df$clarity = cut(df$clarity, breaks=6)

# Create one graph for each size1, plotting the median price vs. the size2 by clarity:
for (c in 1:length(table(df$size1))) {

  mydf = df[df$size1==names(table(df$size1))[c],]
  mydf = aggregate(mydf$price, by=list(mydf$size2, mydf$clarity),median);   
  names(mydf)[1] = 'size2'
  names(mydf)[2] = 'clarity'
  names(mydf)[3] = 'median_price'

  assign(paste("p", c, sep=""), qplot(data=mydf, x=as.numeric(mydf$size2), y=mydf$median_price, group=as.factor(mydf$clarity), geom="line", colour=as.factor(mydf$clarity), xlab = "number of samples", ylab = "median price", main = paste("region number is ",c, sep=''), plot.title=element_text(size=10)) + scale_colour_discrete(name = "clarity")  + theme_bw() + theme(axis.title.x=element_text(size = rel(0.8)), axis.title.y=element_text(size = rel(0.8)) , axis.text.x=element_text(size=8),axis.text.y=element_text(size=8) ))
  }

# Couldnt get some to work, so use:
p5=p4
p6=p4
p7=p4
p8=p4
p9=p4

# Use gridExtra to arrange the 11 plots:

g_legend<-function(a.gplot){
tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
return(legend)}

mylegend<-g_legend(p1)


grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p1 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                     p2 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                     p3 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                     p4 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                     p5 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                     p6 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                     p7 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                     p8 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                     p9 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                     p10 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                     p11 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                     main ="Main title",
                     left = ""), mylegend, 
                    widths=unit.c(unit(1, "npc") - mylegend$width, mylegend$width), nrow=1)
```

Comment: `mylegendwidth` is a vector, you probably want `sum(mylegend$width)` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to change the `qplot` loop call slightly (i.e. put the factors in the data frame) as it was throwing a mismatched size error. I'm not including that bit since that part is obviously working in your environment or it was an errant paste.

Try adjusting your `widths` units like this:

```
widths=unit(c(1000,50),"pt")
```

And you'll get something a bit closer to what you were probably expecting:

And, I can paste code now a few months later :-)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

df <- data.frame(price=matrix(sample(1:1000, 100, replace = TRUE), ncol = 1))

df$size1 = 1:nrow(df)
df$size1 = cut(df$size1, breaks=11)
df=df[sample(nrow(df)),]
df$size2 = 1:nrow(df)
df$size2 = cut(df$size2, breaks=11)
df=df[sample(nrow(df)),]
df$clarity = 1:nrow(df)
df$clarity = cut(df$clarity, breaks=6)

# Create one graph for each size1, plotting the median price vs. the size2 by clarity:
for (c in 1:length(table(df$size1))) {

  mydf = df[df$size1==names(table(df$size1))[c],]
  mydf = aggregate(mydf$price, by=list(mydf$size2, mydf$clarity),median);   
  names(mydf)[1] = 'size2'
  names(mydf)[2] = 'clarity'
  names(mydf)[3] = 'median_price'
  mydf$clarity <- factor(mydf$clarity)

  assign(paste("p", c, sep=""), 
         qplot(data=mydf, 
               x=as.numeric(size2), 
               y=median_price, 
               group=clarity, 
               geom="line", colour=clarity, 
               xlab = "number of samples", 
               ylab = "median price", 
               main = paste("region number is ",c, sep=''), 
               plot.title=element_text(size=10)) + 
           scale_colour_discrete(name = "clarity") + 
           theme_bw() + theme(axis.title.x=element_text(size = rel(0.8)), 
                              axis.title.y=element_text(size = rel(0.8)), 
                              axis.text.x=element_text(size=8),
                              axis.text.y=element_text(size=8) ))
}

# Use gridExtra to arrange the 11 plots:

g_legend<-function(a.gplot){
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
  return(legend)}

mylegend<-g_legend(p1)


grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p1 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                         p2 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                         p3 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                         p4 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                         p5 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                         p6 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                         p7 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                         p8 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                         p9 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                         p10 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                         p11 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                         top ="Main title",
                         left = ""), mylegend, 
             widths=unit(c(1000,50),"pt"), nrow=1)
```

[image: preview here]

**Edit** (16/07/2015): with `gridExtra` >= 2.0.0, the `main` parameter has been renamed `top`.

Comment: Hi hrbrmstr, thank you very much for your help. The legend now is in the right position. If possible, could you please explain what the "widths" in your code is doing?

Comment: the values are expressing - "points" the amount of space each column will be taking up. so there's tons of space for the plots and a smaller amount of space for the legend. I also can paste code & images now and you'll see i had fixed the code to make all the plots work correctly as well.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65832784/r-arranging-multiple-plots-together-using-gridextra thanks!