# Manipulating x axis in panel plot when a factor is used

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, data-visualization, axis-labels

The code I've used is:

```
mcgc <- ggplot(sam, aes(x = person,y = m, colour = X)) +
              geom_point(size = 0.75) +
              scale_colour_gradient2(high="red", mid="green", limits=c(0,1), guide = "colourbar") +
              geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mad, linetype = "mad"), colour = "blue", size=0.75, show_guide = TRUE) +
              geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mmad, linetype = "mmad"), colour = "black", size=0.75, show_guide = TRUE)  +
              facet_wrap(~ Plan, scales = "free", ncol = 4) +
              scale_linetype_manual(name = "Plan of Health Care", values = c("mad" = 1, "mmad" = 1),guide = "legend")
```

For this data:

```
Plan  person X       m  mad  mmad
1  1 95 0.323000 0.400303 0.12
1  2 275 0.341818 0.400303 0.12
1  3  2 0.618000 0.400303 0.12
1  4 75 0.320000 0.400303 0.12
1  5 13 0.399000 0.400303 0.12
1  6 20 0.400000 0.400303 0.12
2  7 219 0.393000 0.353350 0.45
2  8 50 0.060000 0.353350 0.45
2  9 213 0.390000 0.353350 0.45
2  15 204 0.496100 0.353350 0.45
2  19 19 0.393000 0.353350 0.45
2  24 201 0.388000 0.353350 0.45
3  30 219 0.567 0.1254 0.89
3  14 50 0.679 0.1254 0.89
3  55 213 0.1234 0.1254 0.89
3  18 204 0.6135 0.1254 0.89
3  59 19 0.39356 0.1254 0.89
3  101 201 0.300 0.1254 0.89
```

I'm trying to manipulate the x axis using:

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(min(person), median(person), max(person)), labels = c(min(person), median(person), max(person)))
```

However, given that I had to change `person` into a factor to order the data properly, the above code does not work. I get the errors, depending on how I fiddle around with the code:

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L,  : 
  min not meaningful for factors
```

Changing `person` to numeric does not work, as the accumulated `person` for the entire dataset will then be on each Plan figure panel, as opposed to the scale specific for each Plan.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: The x-axis for each panel (Plan) should have a scale beginning from its lowest `Person` to its highest `Person`.  Changing the `Person` to numeric, the x-axis for all panels starts at 1 and goes to 101. For instance, Plan 1 should have an x-axis that goes from 1 to 6 but Plan 3 has one that goes from 14 to 101. Is that clearer? Let me know :)

Comment: Sure - scaling works when `Person` is kept as a factor (as it is because my need to order the data before plotting)... but I want to present the x-axis like so: `scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(min(person), median(person), max(person)), labels = c(min(person), median(person), max(person))) ` which wont work when `Person` is a factor. Hence my change to a numeric which then brings on the x-axis scale problem.

Comment: The picture I posted in the link has on the x axis: min=1 and max=6 for panel 1, min=7 and max=24 for panel 2, and min=14 and max=101 for panel 3. What should be different? Do you want to replace the middle numbers in each panel by their median?

Comment: Yep, exactly.  Only because the data can get very large and there is just way too many `Person`s to fit on the x-axis and I need to reduce it so its legible.

Answer (score 0):

Build the plots separately and group them with functions from the `gridExtra` package.

```
require(ggplot2)

#set breaks and labels (min, median and max) in panel 1
sam1 = subset(sam,sam$Plan==1)
breaks1=c(min(sam1$person),median(sam1$person),max(sam1$person))

plan1 = ggplot(sam1, aes(x = person,y = m, colour=m)) +
  geom_point(size = 2.5) +
  scale_colour_gradient(limits=c(0,1), low="green", high="red", guide="none") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mad, linetype = "solid"), colour = "blue", size=0.75, show_guide = TRUE) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mmad, linetype = "solid"), colour = "black", size=0.75, show_guide = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1)) +
  scale_x_continuous("",breaks=breaks1,labels=breaks1) + 
  ggtitle("1") +
  theme_bw()

#set breaks and labels (min, median and max) in panel 2
sam2=subset(sam,sam$Plan==2)
breaks2=c(min(sam2$person),median(sam2$person),max(sam2$person))

plan2 = ggplot(sam2, aes(x = person,y = m, colour = m)) +
  geom_point(size = 2.5) +
  scale_colour_gradient(limits=c(0,1), low="green", high="red", guide="none") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mad, linetype = "solid"), colour = "blue", size=0.75, show_guide = TRUE) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mmad, linetype = "solid"), colour = "black", size=0.75, show_guide = TRUE)  +
  scale_y_continuous("",limits=c(0,1)) +
  scale_x_continuous("Person",breaks=breaks2,labels=breaks2) +
  ggtitle("2") +
  theme_bw()

#set breaks and labels (min, median and max) in panel 3
sam3=subset(sam,sam$Plan==3)
breaks3=c(min(sam3$person),median(sam3$person),max(sam3$person))

plan3 = ggplot(sam3, aes(x = person,y = m, colour = m)) +
  geom_point(size = 2.5) +
  scale_colour_gradient(limits=c(0,1), low="green", high="red", guide="colourbar") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mad, linetype = "mad"), colour = "blue", size=0.75, show_guide = TRUE) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mmad, linetype = "mmad"), colour = "black", size=0.75, show_guide = TRUE)  +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "Plan of Health Care", values = c("mad" = 1, "mmad" = 1),guide = "legend") +
  scale_y_continuous("",limits=c(0,1)) +
  scale_x_continuous("",breaks=breaks3,labels=breaks3) +
  ggtitle("3") +
  theme_bw()

#using the function form user user971102, posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920662/arrange-many-plots-using-gridextra
g_legend<-function(a.gplot){
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
  return(legend)}

mylegend = g_legend(plan3)

require(gridExtra)

#adjusting panel widths with code adapted from user971102 and hrbrmstr's code, posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920662/arrange-many-plots-using-gridextra
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(plan1 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                         plan2 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                         plan3 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                         ncol=3),mylegend,
                         widths=unit(c(900,90),"pt"),nrow=1)
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect - if I have only 3 Plans/Panels.  Sometimes there are up to 40 Plans, so doing this separately 40 times will get cumbersome (I do have 50+ files of such info so eventually was hoping to set up a loop)... This question (as well as trying to figure out how to change the black line of `mad` in the legend to blue) has to be the most irritating to figure out.  :(  Nevertheless, this is the best solution I've come across to fix this problem.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Since you've provided so much help so far, thought I might ask you if this might work: [MyBreaks function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380417/is-there-a-way-of-manipulating-ggplot-scale-breaks-and-labels) (the function is half way down, under **Update**)? Depending on how I edit it, including this function in my script completely eliminates the x-axis ticks or puts in ticks that don't correspond to min, median and max of each Plan - is there a work around?

Comment: Just to add to the question above => putting in min and max only in the myBreaks function, works... its when median is added, the scales for x goes haywire