# myBreaks function doesn't like median(x) when converting factor variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

This problem stems from a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899719/work-around-for-manipulating-x-axis-using-scale-x-continuous-but-a-factor-is-us). I've come across this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380417/is-there-a-way-of-manipulating-ggplot-scale-breaks-and-labels):

```
myBreaks <- function(x){
breaks <- c(min(as.numeric(as.character(x))),max(as.numeric(as.character(x))))
names(breaks) <- attr(breaks,"labels")
breaks
}
```

Then adding this to the ggplot code with:

```
scale_x_discrete(breaks = myBreaks, labels = myBreaks) +
```

Which works.  However, when adding `median(as.numeric(as.character(x))` to the function, it throws the x-axis haywire.  Is there a work around?

Comment: It might speed things up if you were a little more specific than just saying "haywire".

Comment: Well, putting `min`, `median` and `max` in will plot the `min` correctly, the `median` will not be a number that is reasonable (or not plot it at all) which will then cause the `max` to not be correct (either higher or lower than the actual maximum value).  Removing `median` from the function will mark `min` and `max` properly, so I'm assuming it has a problem calculating the `median`.